# Take with group order by

Tags: c#, linq

I have a web app for calculating the results of a competition:

1. The competitors attempt `x` number of activities (each activity is assigned a point value) over several hours.
2. Their total score is the sum of the 5 highest point values.

I have the following code in my controller. I have tried using `.Take(5)` in several places but it returns either **the top 5 scores only**, or **the first 5 entered in the table**.

The grouping is over several fields as the competitors are awarded prizes by Category (age) and by Gender. I am using a viewmodel named "Game". My most recent unsuccessful code block:

```
var compdata = from result in db.Results
               where result.Complete == true
               orderby result.Activity.Value descending
               group result by new
               {
                   result.CompetitorId,
                   result.Competitor.Name,
                   result.Competitor.Category,
                   result.Competitor.Gender,
               }
               into resultsGroup
               select new Game
               {
                   CompetitorId = resultsGroup.Key.CompetitorId,
                   Name = resultsGroup.Key.Name,
                   Category = resultsGroup.Key.Category,
                   Gender = resultsGroup.Key.Gender,
                   Score = resultsGroup.Sum(s => s.Activity.Value)
               };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're almost there. When working out the `Score` value, you need do the `Take(5)` at that point ... after the grouping. The following *isn't* the most succinct way to do it but it demonstrates the point based on what you have right now:

```
Score = resultsGroup.OrderByDescending(s => s.Activity.Value).Take(5).Sum(s => s.Activity.Value)
```

So that gives something similar to:

```
var compdata = from result in db.Results
               where result.Complete == true
               group result by new
               {
                   result.CompetitorId,
                   result.Competitor.Name,
                   result.Competitor.Category,
                   result.Competitor.Gender,
               }
               into resultsGroup
               select new Game
               {
                   CompetitorId = resultsGroup.Key.CompetitorId,
                   Name = resultsGroup.Key.Name,
                   Category = resultsGroup.Key.Category,
                   Gender = resultsGroup.Key.Gender,
                   Score = resultsGroup.OrderByDescending(s => s.Activity.Value).Take(5).Sum(s => s.Activity.Value)
               };
```